# How to know if a mobile or a device have hardware support for USB accessory mode?

Tags: android

I am trying to build a project which connect android with arduino using Android Open Accessory Development Kit But i found that i could use this Platform with android devices that have hardware support for USB accessory mode.My question is 
How to know if my mobile or a device have hardware support for USB accessory mode?
Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

New Android devices (with ICS) do support accessory mode. However, unfortunately it is not possible to know if comparibly older ones has this feature. It would be better to try the device with an accessory (if possible). The accessory mode is configured at kernel level, and  kernel version should be at least 2.6 and up... But still there might some custom ROMs in which kernel is not compiled to include this feature...

Answer (score 1):

In the developer docs, USB host mode was added in Android 3.1 and greater.

You can filter devices that support USB host with the uses-feature manifest tag

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

Everything is explained here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

Comment: Thank you for  your help.I know that but I am going to buy a new android device to test on it i wil build a completed project includes a Hardware devices (Mobile,arduino and sensors) so  How to know if the mobile(which i will buy have hardware support for USB accessory mode?
from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html
". It is important to note that not all Android 2.3.4 devices are required to support the USB accessory feature. Each individual device manufacturer decides whether or not to support this capability, which is why you must declare it in your manifest file."

Comment: Right, I see your predicament, the docs do not state what happens in the event that a device does not have accessory support, sorry I could not be any more help.